# Have React component trigger a change event the way DOM components would

Tags: javascript, events, reactjs

I have a React Component that wraps an `<input type='text' />` but only calls `onChange` when the value has changed to something valid.  (Its own state allows it to change the text value of the input, but when it calls `onChange`, it actually returns an object of the parsed value of the input.)

```
export default class MyInputClass extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) { 
        super(props);

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

        this.state = { textValue: '' };
        // ...
    }

    // ...

    handleChange(e) {
        // set the state regardless of value so the input's text changes
        this.setState({ textValue: e.target.value});

        // determine whether the value is valid, and if so, call onChange()
        let myObj = MyParsedObject.parse(e.target.value);
        if (myObj !== null && this.props.onChange) {
            this.props.onChange(myObj);
        }
    }

    render() { 
        return <input onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.textValue} />;
    }
}

// ...

MyInputClass.propTypes = {
    onChange: React.PropTypes.func
};
```

Right now I have a property `onChange`, which is a `React.PropTypes.func`, and when the input's change is triggered, I attempt to parse the input's value. If it's successful, I check to see if `this.props.onChange` is not `null`, and then call `onChange(myParsedObject)`.

This works, but it doesn't *feel* right.  Handlers of `onChange` should expect an Event parameter (or SyntheticEvent in React), not an object.  Further, this pattern only allows one handler for `onChange`, whereas real Events can have multiple handlers.

How are you *supposed* to design React Components to emit real events?

Answer (score 1):

If `MyInputClass` is designed to be a *generic* wrapper around inputs, it might make sense to call `this.props.onChange` with the event, rather than the parsed input, and let the parent component decide how to parse it. If, however, `MyInputClass` is a wrapper for a *specific* type of input, it might make sense to also pass on the parsed value. You could always do both, and make it an explicit part of the API:

```
this.props.onChange(e, myObj);
```

Or use `onChange` as the generic handler and `onWhateverChange` as the parsed version; for example, for a `JsonInput` component, you might do

```
this.props.onChange(e);
this.props.onJsonChange(parsedJson);
```

Comment: It is specific.  Do other native JavaScript events pass more than one argument?

Comment: @dfoverdx No, but it's common for composite components to wrap regular HTML elements and provide additional APIs. As long as it's explicit, I don't see the problem. The alternative is to provide your own SyntheticEvent/event value, but I'm not sure how hard that is.